# maven naming GroupId and ArtifactId

Tags: java, maven, project

I am pretty new to maven Projects, and in first few steps of creating one I am asked to enter both GroupId and ArtifactId. Since I am new to maven I don't really understand how does those two work, so I would appreciate some help in both naming them and what significance do they have in the project.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [maven documentation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/):

**groupId**

This element indicates the unique identifier of the organization or group that created the project. The groupId is one of the key identifiers of a project and is typically based on the fully qualified domain name of your organization. For example org.apache.maven.plugins is the designated groupId for all Maven plugins.

**artifactId**

This element indicates the unique base name of the primary artifact being generated by this project. The primary artifact for a project is typically a JAR file. Secondary artifacts like source bundles also use the artifactId as part of their final name. A typical artifact produced by Maven would have the form -. (for example, myapp-1.0.jar).

So along with a version its a way to uniquely identify the artifact in maven.

Each and every artifact is stored in repository, the path to the artifact in the repository has a layout in compliance with group, artifact and version.

Example:

If:

- groupId = com.example
- artifactId=myservice
- version=1.0

Then in the repository you can expect to see the following directory layout:

`com/example/myservice/1.0/myservice-1.0.jar (and Pom.xml)`